# Django noreversematch problems after overriding post_activation_redirect

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm using django-registration(v.0.8) to implement registration. I overrode post_activation_redirect to send users to the page they originally requested by tacking a ?next=/my_next_page/ to the end of the URL.

```
def post_activation_redirect(self, request, user):
        if 'redirect' in request.GET:
            return request.session['redirect'], (), {}
        else:
            return 'top-free-games', (), {}
```

This works fine when redirect is defined, but I'm getting NoReverseMatch errors when it's undefined.

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/activate/d66aaee8a3411ab7a5e495dd024f00a91cd00bec/
Reverse for 'top-free-games' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My urls.py is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TopAppsView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^top-free-games/$', TopFreeAppsView.as_view(), name='top-free-apps'),
    ....
```

This is an app, and the urls are imported through this line:

```
url(r'^app-sales-data/', include('arpu.urls', namespace="arpu")),
```

Is there a good way to systematically debug something like this? I've tried trial and error over and over and it doesn't seem to be digging anything up.

Answer (score 0):

For [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse), you need to specify the [`URL Pattern Name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns), not the `URL path`. so, change `'top-free-games'` to `'top-free-apps'` since that is the name of the url you have specified here:

```
url(r'^top-free-games/$', TopFreeAppsView.as_view(), name='top-free-apps')
```

Comment: Thanks. This was a typo, but not the core issue. I made the change and I'm still getting: Reverse for 'top-free-apps' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: should it not be `'arpu:top-free-apps'` ?

Comment: Yes, that got it. Thanks so much!